# Return date records to nearest minute using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How do I return a list of dates to the nearest minute. I need the linq query to return only dates the match the passed date to the nearest 3 minutes

```
return EntitySet.Count(f => f.VISITDATE == dt.Date);
```

I use the code like this usually:

```
 if((date2 - date1).Minutes <= 3) {
                Console.WriteLine("Do not add again!!");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = EntitySet.Where(item => Math.Abs((item.VISITDATE - dt.Date).TotalMinutes) <= 3);
```

Comment: changed it to var result = EntitySet.Count(item => Math.Abs(((DateTime)item.VISITDATE - dt.Date).TotalMinutes) <= 3);

Comment: Using `Count` instead of `Where` will return the number of dates not the list of dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dates = (from ES in EntitySet
            where ES.VISITDATE >= dt.Date.AddMinutes(-3) && ES.VISITDATE <= dt.Date.AddMinutes(3)
            select ES.VISITDATE)
```